# How to write partial ERB template in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

How to refactor this code? I write on Sinatra I need to separate into a separate file

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <% @user.posts.each do |post| %>
      <a href="/posts/<%= post.id %>"><%= post.title %></a><br>
      <p><%= post.body %></p>
      <% unless post.comment.blank? %>
        <% post.comment.each do |comment| %> 
          <p><%= comment.body %></p>
          <% unless comment.comment.blank? %>
            <% comment.comment.each do |comment2| %> 
              <p><%= comment2.body %></p>
              <% unless comment2.comment.blank? %>
                <% comment2.comment.each do |comment3| %> 
                  <p><%= comment3.body %></p>
                <% end %> 
              <% end %> 
            <% end %> 
          <% end %>   
        <% end %>   
      <% end %> 
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

my model looped comment

```
def up
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :body
      t.integer :post_id
      t.integer :comment_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

This is my migration model comment

Comment: It seems to be question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: And, I don't understand its title.

Comment: I want refactoring code using block or lambda, but don`t know how

Comment: why are you checking to see if comment is `blank?` `.each` will work even on an empty collection object it just wont do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#partials):

> Use it as follows to render the mypartial.haml(1) or the
>   admin/mypartial.haml(2) partials, or with a collection (3) & (4):
>
> ```
> <%= partial(:mypartial) %> <!--(1)-->
> <%= partial(:'admin/mypartial') %> <!--(2)-->
> <%= partial(:object, :collection => @objects) %> <!--(3)-->
> <%= partial(:'admin/object', :collection => @objects) %> <!--(4)-->
> ```
>
> In (1) & (2), the partial will be rendered plain from their files,
>   with no local variables (specify them with a hash passed into
>   :locals). In (3) & (4), the partials will be rendered, populating the
>   local variable object with each of the objects from the collection.

So your code should be:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <% @user.posts.each do |post| %>
      <a href="/posts/<%= post.id %>"><%= post.title %></a><br>
      <p><%= post.body %></p>
      <%= partial(:comment, :collection => post.comment) %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

with the new file `comment.erb`:

```
<p><%= comment.body %></p>
<%= partial(:comment, :collection => comment.comment) %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much helped, I would not have guessed